# Falla al crear una base de datos desde Visual Basic 2015

Tags: programación-bajo-nivel

Buen día,

Compañeros solicito su colaboración informándome la posible solución al siguiente error que me aparece en Visual Basic 2015 cuando intento crear una base de datos local desde VB2015:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy siguiendo los pasos de la siguiente pagina: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms233763(v=vs.110).aspx

Pero no paso del paso 4 de "Crear una nueva base de datos de SQL Server", agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Parece un problema de conexión. Revisaste que la configuración es correcta?

Comment: Pues sigo al pie de la letra lo que recomiendan en la pagina oficial, no se si puede ser alguna configuración adicional o si hay que instalar algo.

Comment: En la página dice como requisito previo: _"Acceso a la base de datos de ejemplo Northwind."_. Lo has hecho?

Answer (score 0):

Buena noche,

La solución era tan sencilla como colocar el nombre de la base de datos igual al nombre del proyecto, no se si era lo correcto pero me funcionó y pude agregar la base de datos.

Muchas gracias a todos.